# Multiple instances of the service - how to guarantee that an object will be processed only once?

Tags: c#, azure

I have the following setup: there are N instances of Azure Worker Role deployed. Our desktop application uploads a message to the Azure, and then a set of images related to the message is uploaded. Message knows what images it needs.

These 2 activities (message upload and images upload) are **independent** - images can be uploaded BEFORE message even generated by user (call it caching - but it's more complex), or few seconds/minutes AFTER message was uploaded to Azure.

I store message in Azure MSSQL database, images are stored in blobs, and URLs to them are stored in database. Also there is *MessageToImage* table which stores links to images for the message. Here is a simplified DB structure (pardon my C#):

```
class Message
{
    public int Id;
    public string Text;
}

class Image
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public string BlobUrl;   // Null if image was not received by the service yet
}

class MessageToImage
{
    public int MessageId;
    public List<int> ImageIds;
}
```

And when we have message with all images ready (i.e. all images are uploaded), we need to do something else with it (let's say, post to Facebook). **HERE IS THE QUESTION:** how can I guarantee that message will be processed only once? In the worst case scenario, I will have N instances receiving N images for the message at the same time - and which instance will "choose" that it should send message to the further processing? And how can I guarantee that it will happen only once?

So far I came up with following ideas:

1. Make sure that "update BlobUrl for Image" database logic will be atomic, and will return number of "missing" images for the message. This way I will trigger further processing only on one instance - the one which receives "0" as the result of database update. BUT: how can I do that on MSSQL level? and more complex - how can i do that using Entity Framework?
2. Have a dedicated worker role which job will be selecting messages which have all images - and send them for processing. But that does not scale well... and looks a bit ugly.

Any other ideas/suggestions?

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE1**
@Richard and @Rob suggested to use Service Bus Queue. I did look into it. The part which I still don't have an answer for is how the piece of code in WORKER ROLE which decides WHEN to send the Message to the Queue for processing should look like? Message gets sent to the queue only when all images are present in the database/blobs (i.e. uploaded to the Azure cloud). And here I would still like to point to my corner-case example - I have 10 images being simultaneously processed by 10 Worker Roles. For all instances processing ends at the same time. Each role updates database with uploaded image URL. And THEN I should somehow trigger final Message processing - meaning one of the instances should get the priority. And I'm not clear HOW I should do this.

Hope this makes my question it a bit cleaner.

Comment: "-1" - dare to explain why?

Answer (score 2):

Create an Azure Service Bus Queue and have your client apps post messages to the queue. Then your worker roles can pull messages from the queue and process the messages.

The great thing about Service Bus Queues is that they guarantee that messages can only be pulled off the queue once, whereupon the message is marked as being 'acquired'. If the transaction is not marked as being completed within (a configurable) time period, the message is returned to the queue ready to be pulled by the next worker request.

This means that if your worker role fails mid-way through processing, the message will eventually reappear in the queue for the next worker to pick it up and (hopefully) complete the required work.

Read this for more information:

[How to use Service Bus Queues](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-queues/)

Comment: thanks for answering. I did look into Service Bus Queue, however my concern remains the same. I updated my question - please take a look.

Comment: From your update above, it's not clear who's uploading images - client or worker role? As I understand your scenario, your client uploads a stack of images and then sends a message to the queue requesting that the images are processed. Your worker role(s) can then pull messages from the queue and process the images listed in the message. No need for SQL at all!

Comment: client knows nothing about queues etc. Client (desktop app) uploads images AND message to worker role. After message arrives, worker role needs to wait for all images, and then send message for further processing.

Comment: @avs. Can client be modified to post message to Azure queue? Client could also be modified to post message AFTER all images have been uploaded (I suggest uploading images directly to Blob storage). This way, worker role won't need to check whether images have been uploaded and can just pull messages from queue and process accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [Service Bus Messaging Sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj863132.aspx)

On your client generate a unique batch upload Id for the upload session (use a GUID rather than int). Each image that is uploaded should be accompanied by this Id (same Id for all images in your upload batch). When your service receives the image it posts an "Upload Image" BrokeredMessage to a Service Bus Queue or Topic with the SessionId set to the unique Id supplied by the client.

When your Message is sent from the client to the service, send the batch upload Id with it. When this is received from the service post a "Process All Uploads" BrokeredMessage on another Queue/Topic. The receiver of this BrokeredMessage will read the batch upload Id, and then start listening for all "Upload Image" messages associated with the relevant sessionId. It can continue doing this until it has received them all (might need to send a total uploaded count so it knows when to stop). Once it has received them all it can generate a new BrokeredMessage to trigger processing of the image upload (e.g post to facebook).

You want to generate a seperate BrokeredMessage for the final processing stage (post to facebook) so that if your role fails while processing the message, the message will be re-delivered a little while later.

Something to keep in mind is that messages are received "At Least Once", if your role fails midway through processing a message the message will return to the queue/topic after a timeout. So your processing logic needs to be able to handle the case where it is processing a message that it had already previously partially processed.

Here is roughly what the various actors should be doing to achieve what you want:

### Client(s)

- Generate a unique sessionId (or request one from your web service)
- Upload each image to web role, with associated sessionId
- Upload a job "Message" to web role, with associated sessionId and imageCount in upload batch (can be done before/during/after image uploads)

### Web Role(s)

- When receiving an uploaded image, store image in blob storage, post to a Queue ("UploadsQueue") a BrokeredMessage with the SessionId set and Body containing image URL
- When reveiving an uploaded job "Message", post to a Queue ("JobsQueue") a "UploadBatch" BrokeredMessage with the Body containing the sessionID and imageCount

### Worker Roles(s)

- When receiving an "UploadBatch" message from the "JobsQueue", get the sessionId and imageCount from the message body, AcceptMessageSession(sessionId) on the "UploadsQueue" and keep polling for messages in that session until you receive all the upload messages. Once (receivedCount == imageCount) post a "SendToFacebook" message to "JobsQueue", with list of images to process etc in the Body
- When receiving a "SendToFacebook" message from the "JobsQueue", get the list of images to process from message body and send them to facebook etc

Comment: thanks for your answer. I updated my question, please take a look.

Comment: The trick is to post a BrokeredMessage for each image when they are uploaded, rather than trying to post a single message when they are all finished uploading. I will update my answer with some more details on which bits are done by workerRole/webRole/client

Comment: hmmm... so basically I need ANOTHER worker role instance which will listen to the Queue and do final processing - am I correct? I was hoping to "spread" final processing between 10 instances I already have to be honest.

Comment: You can have your existing image processing worker roles also listening to the second queue and do the final processing, you may want to start some threads to listen to each of the queues, rather than having a single loop on one queue inside your WorkerRole.Run method